# PLS-00312: a positional parameter association may not follow a named association

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql

Anyone know how I can avoid the PLS-00312 Error here?

"PLS-00312: a positional parameter association may not follow a named association"

I am getting this because of the following line:

```
AttachList=> v_est_proc_name||'_EST_PROC.csv',v_prd_segs||'_PRD_SEGS.csv',
```

In the below procedure:

```
create or replace procedure send_csv as

v_tomail varchar2(40);
v_est_proc_name varchar2(40);
v_prd_segs varchar2(40); 

cursor c1 is
SELECT email_address
INTO v_tomail
FROM mail where
mdate = (select max(mdate) FROM blah)
group by email_address  
order by max(mdate) desc;

begin
open c1;
fetch c1 into v_tomail;

SELECT tablename into v_est_proc_name
FROM blah_blah
WHERE
CREATED_AT = (select MAX(CREATED_AT) from blah);

SELECT tablename into v_prd_segs
FROM blah_blah
WHERE
CREATED_AT = (select MAX(CREATED_AT) from blah);

mail.send_mail.send(
ToList=> v_tomail,
Subject=> 'see attachments',
Body=> 'Please action the attached files for this request.',
FromEmail=> 'donotreply@mail.com', 
FromHost=> 'host',
SMTPServer=> 'host',
AttachList=> v_est_proc_name||'_EST_PROC.csv',v_prd_segs||'_PRD_SEGS.csv',

Directory=> 'CSV_DIR');
End;
```

I just don't know how to get rid of it... there must be a way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See here where you say:

AttachList=>  v_est_proc_name||'_EST_PROC.csv',**v_prd_segs||'_PRD_SEGS.csv',**

The bit in bold is being treated as an individual argument to mail.send_mail.send() but it doesn't have an argument name in front of it like all the other arguments do, so oracle doesn't know which argument it's supposed to be for

Supply a name of which argument this data is supposed to be. If you're trying to send multiple attachments, I think it's supposed to be a comma separated string but your comma is outside of any string and oracle is thinking it's a comma that separates the function argument list (two arguments)

Try something like:

```
AttachList=> v_est_proc_name||'_EST_PROC.csv,'||v_prd_segs||'_PRD_SEGS.csv',
```

This puts the comma separating the filenames inside the string

The error basically means "you can only mix positional arguments and named arguments if you put the positional ones first then switch to named"

For a function:

```
F(a, b, c)

--these are ok
F(1,2,3). --positional arguments go in order
F(c=> 3, b=> 2, a=> 1) --named arguments any order
F(1. c=> 3, b=> 2) --mixed, a is 1 in order, other two are any order

--going back to using positional after you started using names is not ok
F(b=> 2, 1, 3)
```

It's an error in the last example because oracle cannot decide on its own whether A is 1 or 3 (and hence C is 3 or 1)

Edit:

OK, possibly I've been working with SQLS too long and forgot my Oracle. If you're asserting that you cannot string concat values together for an argument (i.e. you have to store them in a variable first), why not try this:

```
SELECT tablename||'_EST_PROC.csv,' into v_est_proc_name
FROM blah_blah
WHERE
CREATED_AT = (select MAX(CREATED_AT) from blah);

SELECT v_est_proc_name||tablename||'_PRD_SEGS.csv' into v_est_proc_name
FROM blah_blah
WHERE
CREATED_AT = (select MAX(CREATED_AT) from blah);

mail.send_mail.send(
ToList=> v_tomail,
Subject=> 'see attachments',
Body=> 'Please action the attached files for this request.',
FromEmail=> 'donotreply@mail.com', 
FromHost=> 'host',
SMTPServer=> 'host',
AttachList=> v_est_proc_name,
```

You could probably also consider a bigger size for the string (40 is a bit small?) and a better name. I've tried to test this, but I don't have a live oracle instance, and haven't had any success in making the various fiddle sites create functions..

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Appreciate it! I tried with the comma, that isn't accepted

Comment: Made an edit to try and help out, but it's not really clear to me what "that isn't accepted" means

Comment: Ps I used this site http://www.oracletool.com/blog/?p=64 in my assertion that multiple files attached are comma separated - I've never used this package myself, just acquired the knowledge of how to attach multiple files from that article

Answer (score 4):

The message is self-explanatory.

Suppose you have a procedure or a function (let's say a procedure, to be specific), `my_proc`, with four parameters:

```
my_proc(param1, param2, param3, param4)
```

Given values for the four parameters, `arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4`, you can call the procedure like this:

```
my_proc(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4)
```

-- this uses **positional** parameter association. The order of the arguments has meaning.

You can also call it like this:

```
my_proc(param1 => arg1, param3 => arg3, param2 => arg2, param4 => arg4)
```

-- this uses **named** parameter association. The order of the "associations" no longer has meaning - you can put the assignments (associations) in any order you like, as long as you pair the right argument with the right parameter name.

You can also mix them, but you can ONLY use positional association first, followed by named association. This is legal:

```
my_proc(arg1, arg2, param4 => arg4, param3 => arg3)
```

but this is illegal:

```
my_proc(arg1, param3 => arg3, param2 => arg2, arg4)
```

There are very good reasons for this, but the reasons are irrelevant; this is a syntax requirement which your code must follow even if there weren't good reasons for it.

In your code, all the associations are named, except the argument (value)

```
v_prd_segs||'_PRD_SEGS.csv'
```

which is **not** assigned to a specific, named parameter.

To fix it, use the name of the parameter that should accept this argument, like you did for all the other parameters.

Comment: In my code I'm trying to use the variables v_prd_segs and v_est_proc_name, but just with some text tagged on... it seems from the explanations here (Thank you!!) that I can't do that in pl/sql here, I have to use an entire declared variable. Is there a way to actually declare the whole thing, for example v_est_proc_name||'_EST_PROC.csv' as a variable and do it that way?

Answer (score 0):

Try to look at this line again:

```
AttachList=> v_est_proc_name||'_EST_PROC.csv',v_prd_segs||'_PRD_SEGS.csv',
```

Its two arguments NOT one.

```
AttachList=> v_est_proc_name||'_EST_PROC.csv',
????      => v_prd_segs||'_PRD_SEGS.csv',
```

Try to find the parameter name that should match the ??? in the mail.send_mail.send procedure.